# Unexpected behaviour while playing audio in Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

[image]

I'm learning JavaScript and created this very simple page. All it does is, when Pikachu(image) is clicked , an audio file is played.

Similarly, If I type the string "Pikachu" in the form, it plays the same sound, else it says "not found".

I have the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Pokemon Cries</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sounds.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="inputform" type="text" name="search">
            <button onclick="getdata()">Search</button>
        </form>
        <img class="images" src="images/pikachu.png" alt="Pikachu" onclick="pikachusound()">
    </body>
</html>
```

My JS is

```
var pikachu=new Audio("sounds/pikachu.mp3");

var inputstring;

function getdata()
{
    inputstring=document.getElementById("inputform").value;
    if(inputstring.toLowerCase()=="pikachu")
    {
        pikachusound();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Not found");
    }
}
function pikachusound()
{
    pikachu.play();
}
```

and MY CSS is

```
body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
.images{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: grey;
}
```

Clicking on the image works very fine, and it plays that audio. But when I input "Pikachu" in the form , it plays the sound sometimes , other times it doesn't.

After searching a lot on the web , I'can't find the reason for this unexpected behavior.

Can anyone please help in finding the bug? Thank You.

Comment: Add event.preventDefault(); in the getdata function.

Comment: @sphinxplayer Better yet, don't use a form and a submit button here since there is no form submission taking place.

Comment: But then you are modifying the HTML. Thats not what he asked for.

Comment: @sphinxplayer He asked for help with the bug. The bug is that the HTML is incorrect. HTML is about semantics and structure. A `form` with a `submit` button are not the correct elements to be using here - - they are the bug. Adding `.preventDefault()` is a band-aid, but it doesn't actually get to the heart of the problem.

Comment: There is no submit button in the form. No it is not a bug. He told us he his learning and what if this is only the beginning of his form ?

Comment: @sphinxplayer If you read my answer, you'd know that there is a `submit` button on the form. `submit` is the default type of `button`.  I don't want to argue with you. Based on the information given, the bug/problem is the form and submit button and that's exactly how my answer starts out.

Comment: If you read my previous comment, this might not be the final structure of his form. event.preventDefault(); makes it work as it is right now.

Comment: I did read your comment. `event.preventDefault()` is not correct even if he has more to his form because it disables the submit event. Not using a `submit` button when you are not `submitting` is the correct answer. He clearly doesn't want to submit when the button gets clicked. His code shows us that because you don't start playing an audio file and then redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure because you can only tell us that "sometimes" it works and "sometimes" it doesn't. But, one culprit could be that you are using a `form` with a `submit` button (that's the default type of `button` you get when you don't specify the `type` attribute). When a `form` is submitted (automatically triggered from the `click` of a `submit` button), the page is redirected, which would cause any other code on the page to cease. In that case, it's a bit of a "race" between `getData()` running and the `form` submitting and which one wins won't always be the same.

I would suggest you don't use a `form` here because it doesn't appear that you are really submitting any data anywhere.

You are also using some very old techniques for coding in general, so take a look at the code below and note the comments.

```js
var pikachu= new Audio("sounds/pikachu.mp3");
    
// Get a reference to the input element just once, not every time
// the function needs to run and don't set your variable to a property
// of the element, set it to the element itself. That way, if you 
// ever decide that you want to access another property of the element
// you don't have to re-scan for it.
var inputElement = document.getElementById("inputform");
var imageElement = document.querySelector("img[alt='Pikachu']");
var buttonElement = document.querySelector("button[type='button']");

// Don't set up events in the HTML with inline event handlers like "onclick"
// Follow modern standards and do all your event binding in JavaScript
buttonElement.addEventListener("click", getdata);
imageElement.addEventListener("click", pikachusound);
    
// In JavaScript, it's a best practice to put the opening curly brace {
// on the same line as the structure it defines because under certain
// circumstances, the code will actually run differently than when the
// brace is on the next line down.
function getdata() {
   if(inputElement.value.toLowerCase() == "pikachu") {
      pikachusound();
   } else {
      alert("Not found");
   }
}

function pikachusound(){
  console.log("Sound playing!");
  pikachu.play();
}
```

```css
body{
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
}
   
.images{
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   margin: 20px;
   border: 5px solid grey;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input id="inputform" type="text" name="search">
<!-- To get a regular button, specify the type -->
<button type="button">Search</button>

<img class="images" src="images/pikachu.png" alt="Pikachu">
```